# How to close Popup dialog in code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

[Popup dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M71Xp.png)

My purpose of closing this popup dialog is when some filters in my page was changed this popup dialog is no longer relevant so I wanted to close it under my List item SelectedIndexChanged event but I could find any solution yet. Although user can just click the close button but It would be better if it can be done in code.

Glad if you can help. Thanks

Comment: This looks like IE download message, so I don't get how a previous download is irrelevant. Anyhow you should provide some relevant code.

Comment: Previous download will become irrelevant to the current page values because the filter was changed. What I want is when any of the filters was changed this download message will be closed so user don't need to close it manually.

Comment: A download is always what it was when you requested it, and not what you see on the screen. This is a browser feature, and not a part of your application. Even if it is possible, it would be a bad UX to change this behavior.

Comment: I see. So, this means i just leave it to user to close it manually. Thanks.